# CSS:: Second layer of solid non transparent background on top of transparent background is not working?

Tags: html, css, image, filter, opacity

Title is pretty much self explanatory (and surprising?)

I have 3 layer :

1. background Image
2. Transparent div
3. NON Transparent div on top of transparent div.

Not very helpful css tricks to solve the problem:

```
1. filter: alpha(opacity=100);

2. opacity: 1;

3. z-index: 2;

4. background:url('someSolidWhitePicture.jpg');
```

Here is the jsFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/gu0ndhbx/

Here is the full code example :

The HTML:

```
<div id="heziGangina">
    <div id="ganginaHezi">
    Dummy Text (that should be inside non transparent background)...
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body
{
background: url('http://moreimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/iPhone-Wallpaper-HD-010-640x600.jpg');
z-index: 0;
}


#heziGangina
{
background: #fff;
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: 300px;
z-index: 1;
}

#ganginaHezi
{
background: #fff;
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px auto;
z-index: 2;
background: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/plain_white_background_211387.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of the opacaity given in the parent div.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu0ndhbx/1/).

```
body{
    background:url('http://moreimg.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/iPhone-Wallpaper-HD-010-640x600.jpg');
    /* z-index:0; */
}


#heziGangina{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: 300px;
}

#GanginaHezi{
   width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 10px auto;
background: url('http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicmedium/plain_white_background_211387.jpg');
background-size: 100px;
}
```